# Filter between directives

Tags: angularjs, filter, directive

I have a problem, i don't know how to do this:

I have to many lists in angular in a ng-repeat inside a directive `listItems` and inside other directive i have the filters to attack the list `filterItems`, both are inside a route with a controller, how can i get the filters from the directive `filterItems` and use it in `listItems`?

Another question are the filters aren't the same in the list, one list can have a filters and another different list other filters, i don't know if i'm doing it good, hope you can help me,

Thank you!

**EDIT**

I have a route like this:

```
templateUrl: 'section.html',
controller: 'sectionCtrl'
```

and inside `section.html` i have something like this:

```
<div>
    <filter section="section"></filter>
    <list-items></list-items>
</div>
```

in filter directive i have a couple of selects, checkboxes and the input to search in the list, how can i send the filter from filter directive to listItems directive? hope this explanation helps more! thanks!

Comment: A jsfiddle link would be appreciated, for a better understanding of your issue :)

Comment: updated with a better explanation